# how do I get an element out from the forEach loop

Tags: javascript

Please tell me how do I get that `AllMainSongsIndex` out from the *loop* and how do I use it

```
songsItems.forEach((element, i) => {
      let Allcovers = element.querySelectorAll(".cover")
      Allcovers[0].src = songs[i].coversPath
      let AllNames = element.getElementsByClassName("Names");
      AllNames[0].innerHTML = songs[i].songName;
      let AllMainSongsIndex=element.querySelector(".currentsoundGIF").id;
      return AllMainSongsIndex;
});
```

Thank you in advanced

Comment: [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value) explicitly returns `undefined`.  But as noted in the answer, even if this returned you would only get the last element query (and you're not assigning it to anything). What is it you are actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Define it outside the loop, assign inside the loop and use it outside the loop. But it's confusing about which one you want to use, may be use some logic to use a particular value, in your case the last loop element will get assigned.

```
let AllMainSongsIndex= "";

songsItems.forEach((element, i) => {
      let Allcovers = element.querySelectorAll(".cover")
      Allcovers[0].src = songs[i].coversPath
      let AllNames = element.getElementsByClassName("Names");
      AllNames[0].innerHTML = songs[i].songName;
      AllMainSongsIndex=element.querySelector(".currentsoundGIF").id;
});
// Use it here
```